# Looping number in menu prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I got a problem with looping number in a menu.

Here is the coding:

```
la3:-nl,
    write('-------MENU-------'),nl,
    write('1. Biodata'),nl,
    write('2. Looping Number'),nl,
    write('3. Exit'),nl,
    write('Choose : '),read(Z),
    (
    Z=1,nl,
    write('BIODATA'),nl,
    write('Input your name : '),read(J),nl,
    write('Input your Identity number : '),read(K),nl,
    write('Input your class : '),read(L),nl,
    write('---------------------'),nl,
    write('Name : '),write(J),nl,
    write('Identity number : '),write(K),nl,
    write('Class : '),write(L),nl,
    la3;

    Z=2,nl,
    write('LOOPING NUMBER'),nl,
    loop(0),
    loop(N):-N>0,write('Value : '),write(N),nl,
    M is N-1,loop(M),
    la3;



    Z=3,nl,
    write('EXIT'),nl
    ).
```

I have no idea how to do the looping and the code above doesn't work.

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to do, and the results you have seen from trying the code you have posted?

Comment: You have some syntax issues here. Particularly, `... loop(0), loop(N) :- N > 0, ...`

Comment: If you're doing this for yourself, have you seen SWI Prolog's [`library(tty)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/tty.pl)? There's a nice `menu/3` predicate in there for building these kinds of menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the few things Prolog does have in common with other languages is that it's best to think modularly. It looks like you're trying to capture all functionality in one predicate clause which is awkward and poor structure.

Start first by getting a top level menu working. This is based upon a common, simple loop pattern in Prolog: `repeat, ..., fail`.

```
main :-
    repeat,
    write('-------MENU-------'), nl,
    write('1. Biodata'), nl,
    write('2. Looping Number'), nl,
    write('3. Exit'), nl,
    write('Choose : '),
    read(Z),
    ( Z = 3 -> !, fail ; true ),  % fail without backtrack if Z = 3
    action_for(Z),
    fail.
```

Then you can work on `action_for/1`. Here's a stub for `action_for/1`:

```
action_for(X) :-
    write('Action for '),
    write(X), nl.
```

When you execute it, you get this:

```
| ?- main.
-------MENU-------
1. Biodata
2. Looping Number
3. Exit
Choose : 1.
Action for 1
-------MENU-------
1. Biodata
2. Looping Number
3. Exit
Choose : 2.
Action for 2
-------MENU-------
1. Biodata
2. Looping Number
3. Exit
Choose : 3.

no
| ?-
```

So the basic looping and menu behavior is in place.

I'll leave proper implementation of `action_for/1` as an exercise.

Comment: i mean, i've been searching looping number but when i put into the menu it just doesnt work

Comment: @Pratama does my answer clear things up for you? There's really not a good way to fix the existing code. It needs restructuring since it attempts to be imperative, whereas Prolog is relational.